tessract fails to extract text from image with leptonica error?
I'm downloading file from a windows machine and store it to linux machine
with below code I'm getting error which I've added.
Below code is running on Ubuntu 16.04
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.04.01 with Leptonica ERROR: Can not open input file /home/user/indrajit/windows/<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=1536x638 at 0x7F457C9317F0> Error during processing.'), location : /home/user/indrajit/screenshot.jpeg

my code is. :


def take_screenshot_and_analyse_text(platform):
    file_name = "screenshot.jpeg"
    directory_path = "C:\\Users\winauto\AppData\Local\Temp\\"
    linux_screenshot_download_path = f"/home/user/indrajit/{file_name}"

    try:
        platform.take_screenshot(path=directory_path, file_name=file_name)
        logger.info(f"Screenshot saved at {platform.os.path.join(directory_path, file_name)}")
        platform.download_file(remote_path=platform.os.path.join(directory_path, file_name), local_path=linux_screenshot_download_path)
        logger.info(f"File successfully downloaded to {linux_screenshot_download_path}")
        os.chmod(linux_screenshot_download_path, 0o777)
        extracted_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(f"{Image.open(linux_screenshot_download_path)}")
        logger.info(f"Extracted Text is : \n\n {extracted_text}")

    except Exception as err:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
        logger.info(f"Failed to extract text from screenshot: {err}, location : {linux_screenshot_download_path}")



